# Red Herring Bonkers In The Red Herring Bunkers

Tags: riddle, three-dimensional

### Please help me!

Last weekend I hosted a hell of a party at my workplace (I'll invite you next time, promise). Of course, my boss didn't know about it.
The next morning I entered the building and everything was just a huge mess! Naive as I am, I was expecting something less wicked and wanted to clean everything up before my boss would be able to see any of this. But see for yourself...

In the heat of the moment I've also created some rough sketches so you can see how the whole place is looking without the surrounding walls
(for controls and all that see [my other 3D riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40806/the-brain-curdling-eldritch-horrors-and-the-third-dimension) and for those who can't use the 3D I will provide screenshots on demand):

---

[image]
[Meeting Room (click this link for 3D)](http://www.viewstl.com/?embedded&orientation=bottom&shading=flat&bgcolor=white&color=gray&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhjeolpv2zfj3yj/mid.stl?dl=1&edges=yes)

---

[image]
[IT Department (click this link for 3D)](http://www.viewstl.com/?embedded&orientation=bottom&shading=flat&bgcolor=white&color=gray&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ugl8vxz3h3huke/bot.stl?dl=1&edges=yes)

---

[image]
[Main Office (click this link for 3D)](http://www.viewstl.com/?embedded&orientation=bottom&shading=flat&bgcolor=white&color=gray&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dxdjj72itc7w64/top.stl?dl=1)

---

After some looking around I noticed the message on the screens and I started to get the idea. I'm now trying to figure out some kind of pass phrase hidden behind multiple layers of secrecy, so I can unlock the computers and won't have to pay the ransom. Not sure where to start, yet. I didn't move anything to make sure I didn't wipe any prints or clues.

I thought it would be useful to get some other views on this from different angles. So I wanted to ask you for your help. 
If you can tell me the password I'll pay 300 rep. Sadly, that's all I can pay at the moment (credit card bill coming soon). Meanwhile I'm thinking of a way to tell my boss about the party and all the rep her company loses... good luck to me and to you!

---

**Hints:**

Hint 1

> Snooping around my desk might be helpful.

Hint 2

> For some parts of the solution it may not be irrelevant to figure out how the floors stack.

Hint 3

> For some parts of the solution it may not be relevant to figure out how the floors stack.

hint 4

> Think bigger than last time.

Comment: Give it some time to load. 2 days maybe.

Comment: Is just amazing. Which tool did you use to create this ?

Comment: @lois6b You can use pretty much any 3D CAD software. I used "Creo Elements/Direct Modeling Express"  here, since it's free for students and I'm familiar with it.

Comment: Is there any online viewer that lets us see the model in color? There are so many elements that color would help a lot for us to keep track of where we are.

Comment: @EngineerToast I spent about one month to make a coloured version available for everyone. Unfortunately without any success. Online viewers have limits regarding file sizes that's why I'm working with the STL format. However, that format doesn't store colour information as far as I know.

Comment: Someone made a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46370/red-herring-bonkers-in-the-red-herring-bunkers) to discuss this puzzle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The passphrase is:

> **AWESOME**

How to find it:

> It's basically an anagram of a couple of letters that can be found in the puzzle. Most were already found by others, I'll include them for the sake of completeness.
>
>  **Hint 2** says: *"For some parts of the solution it may not be irrelevant to figure out how the floors stack."*, additionally **hint 4** says: *"Think bigger than last time."*. Using both of them, we can find a couple of letters, when we place all floors correctly one above other.
>
>  Looking from the top we can see an **S** formed by the bookshelves and an **E** formed by the desks:
>
>  [image: SE]
>
>  Looking from the side we can see an **E** formed by the couches:
>
>  [image: E]
>
>  Looking from another side we can see an **O** formed by the plants:
>
>  [image: O]
>
>  **Hint 3** tells us the opposite of hint 2: *"For some parts of the solution it may not be relevant to figure out how the floors stack."*, which means we have to look for letters on separate floors as well.
>
>  There is an **M**, when we look through the window of the main office (from the outside):
>
>  [image: M]
>
>  One display in the main office shows the following message:
>
>  [image: first]
>
>  The first letter of the alphabet is **A**, and it is also the first letter of the phrase. The books on the coffee table in the main office contain *"Avi's secret riddles"*, which is also a hint for **A** (the first letter):
>
>  [image: A]
>
>  In the meeting room is a board with "WC" on it, looking through the window we are supposed to see only the letter **W** (doesn't work very well with the viewers I have):
>
>  [image: W]
>
>  With all the remaining red herrings it wasn't really clear to me what the answer was, until the following comment in the chat: *"I think the solution will be, like all my solutions, a very simple and meaningless word telling you how good you are"*

Comment: Well done fellow riddler ;)

Comment: I wonder how on Earth someone can find some random letters in the arrangement of furnitures out of many possible others. I would fail to solve it even if someone tells me that I have to look the arrangement of furnitures.

Answer (score 5):

## Partial answer: Some findings so far

### Clues

- In the meeting room, the board says WC on it.
- In the main office, the board farthest back in the pile has an M on its back. - The tipped-over computer monitor in the main office (on the desk, not the floor) says "The first letter is the first letter".

### Possibly Clues

- There are several copies of his previous puzzle scattered around the rooms. None of them seem to have the treasure chest inside, but I may have missed one.
- The main office has a picture frame with a "5" on it. It seems to be the same as the one from the previous puzzle.
- Two of the cubes in the IT department have things from around the office on it. The top is a potted plant, laying down; the four sides are a combo bookshelf+drawer, a couch, and a desk with a computer (that just has the same "You've been hacked" message as the rest). There is nothing on the bottom or back.

### Not Clues

- In the main office, the coffee cups spell out "nice try" in binary. I assume this is not a clue to anything, and is just Avigrail laughing at me.
- In the fridge, there's a message saying "DO NOT STEAL FOOD FROM THE FRIDGE YOU WANKER". Also probably not a clue.
- In the IT department is a frame with "Riddler's Den" on it and one with a red fish - presumably a red herring.
- ~~The copies of the cube by the computer in the IT department have "329" inside the cylinders.~~ It was confirmed by Avigrail that I was reading this the wrong way: it was PSE instead.

Comment: Yeah, the binary was meant for you. Good job ;)

Comment: There's also a PC inside which is a message ONLY PORN IN HERE.

Comment: It seems like there might be a lot of information in the way the books on the shelves are pushed forward or backward.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There are limits, even for me. I think they are just books. You see, I was forced to work without colours due to the file format. In order to make it look like books I had to move some of them back and forth.

Comment: Oh, what a disappointment! :-)

Comment: Compositing all floors together, the countertops make an `S` or `5` shape. I don't yet see patterns in the other furniture.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've found so far:

Meeting Room:

> The poster in the just says "W C", with one letter on top of the other.

IT Department:

> One frame says "RIDDLERS DEN"
>  Next to it is a frame with a silhouette of a fish, head pointing up, tail pointing down.
>  All computer monitors in the room display the following:
>  YOU'VE BEEN
>  HACKED
>  PAY 500 REP
>  OR WE DELETE
>  EVERYTHING

Main Office

> One monitor says:
>  THE FIRST
>  LETTER IS
>  THE FIRST
>  LETTER
>  All other monitors have the same message as the IT Department. Yes, even the monitor that's lying face down: [image: You've been hacked, pay 500 rep or we delete everything]
>  There's a frame with the number 5 on it.
>  Next to the sink, there are a bunch of empty frames, and one frame with the letter M.

<del>I'm not sure how to figure out the order of the letters, though.</del>
It occurred to me that the passphrase might be presented in the form of...

> ...a rebus. As such, I will attempt to process the information that @Deusovi and I have found, organized with the floor structure that @MMAdams was the first to figure out:

First floor (IT Department):

> The furniture cube and the ransomware message seem to be the only meaningful objects in this room. The cubes are configured as follows:
>  Top: potted plant. Not "facing" any direction, but the top of the plant is next to side 3, and the bottom of the pot is next to side 4.
>  Side 1, lined up with the framed red herring: couch/sofa, facing the floor.
>  Side 2, lined up with the stairs: a desk with a chair and a computer displaying the ransomware message, with the chair facing the red herring wall.
>  Side 3, opposite side 2: cabinet/bookshelf, facing the ceiling.
>  Side 4, opposite side 1: bare.
>  The bottom of the cube can be assumed to be bare as well, since it's lying flat on the floor.
>  The other furniture cube is identical, but its sides are perpendicular to the walls of the room, and would therefore be even more cumbersome to describe, lacking a compass.
>  The cubes from the previous puzzle have the number 5 on its side, although one cube is tilted, so the 5 is almost upright.
>  Frustratingly little to work with here, moving on.

Second floor (Meeting Room):

> This has the most clearly rebus-like clue, with the "W over C" board. Could also be "C under W", which might be "see underwater", but it's a stretch.
>  The cubes on this floor also have 5 on its side.

Third floor (Main Office):

> At first I thought I found a new clue, but probably not. Each of the books on the coffee table have the words "AVI'S SECRET RIDDLES" inside of them.
>  The frame on the wall has the number 5 right side up.
>  On second thought, the books probably ARE a clue: "the first letter is the first letter" is probably about this. If I'm right about this, the first letter of the answer is A.

Comment: It's getting better and better :)

Answer (score 4):

In response to hint 2, The floors are stacked in the following order:

> The IT Department is on the bottom floor (you can see it lacks a railing indicating where the drop off to the stairs is)
> The Meeting Room is in the middle, containing both a staircase and a railing indicating another staircase) Also, the railing matches where the stairs from the IT Department are.
> The Main Office is on the top floor, because there are no stairs leading up

Comment: You must be a natural!